# How could I get rid of these shared_ptr/weak_ptr in this entity-component architecture?

Tags: c++, entity-component

We've built an entity-component architecture that works ok for our needs, but it has something that bugs me a bit from a software engineering point of view.

We use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` for the `Component`s: the `Entity` owns the component through an `std::shared_ptr`, while the `ComponentManager` and other `Component`s refer to the component through a non-owning `std::weak_ptr`.

The issue is that the components are not actually shared, and they should not be shared either. They're owned by a single entity. Having an `std::shared_ptr` there suggests that anyone can take a copy of the `shared_ptr` and own it too.

Here is a diagram of how the classes are organized:

[image]

`Entity`:

- real owner of the components through `shared_ptr`
- does not know which components it holds

`ComponentManager`:

- we call `update()` on the `ComponentManager`, which in turn calls `update()` on every component it knows about
- there is one instance per type of component; we've done it like this to have control over which components get updated first (e.g. `CmpRigidBody` updates the `CmpMatrixTransform`, and from which the `CmpGfx` is then updated)
- unofficial owners of the components through `weak_ptr`s; it's "unofficial" because it's through them that the components are updated
- `weak_ptr`s are stored in a `vector`
- once the (single) `shared_ptr` goes out of scope (e.g. when the entity gets deleted), a custom deleter tells the ComponentManager to remove the `weak_ptr` from the `vector` (this also adds confusion to this architecture)

`Component` and derived:

- holds the core of the information and performs the main operations of the component
- can reference other components through `weak_ptr` (hooked up at initialization, for now)

I strongly believe in using the right tool for the job, and although this architecture works, I'm curious to see if there are alternatives that would remove the confusion introduced by the shared_ptrs.

Maybe this is pertinent:

- The amount of entities and components is relatively low, so we won't gain much by making efforts to keep them close together (the rendering and the physics simulation are taking most of our frame time).
- We use this approach because of the re-usability offered by the components and entities from project to project.
- The project is single-threaded.
- The action takes place in the `Component`, not in the `ComponentManager` (i.e. it's a entity-component architecture, not an entity-component-system archiecture), so the `Component` needs access to other `Component`s if they still exist, and these can be removed at any time.

I could use a kind of handle system through the `ComponentManager` and query the appropriate one every time I need an access to a `Component`, but this adds a dependency... (Maybe that's the price to pay..?!)

Do I have other options?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a single owner and you can properly handle clearing dangling pointer it is fine to use `unique_ptr` for the owner and raw pointers for the non-owners.

You shouldn't be allocating separate components like that. This is a cache nightmare. Especially when you combine it with virtual function calls. Once the order of components is somewhat randomized due to add and remove churn the branch predictor will no help at all and you will hit cache misses a lot when trying to call `update()` on every component.

Instead put all components of the same type into a separate vector. And use a non-virtual function to update them.

```
foreach(CmpGfx& comp: manager.getGraficsComponents()){
    updateGfx(comp);
}
```

This lets it get inlined which in turn allows for interleaving of each iteration and further optimizations.

Even better if you can fix the index per entity then you don't need to keep a pointer in the Graphics component to the matrix component.

```
foreach(std::tuple<CmpGfx&, CmpMatrix&> comp: manager.getComponents<CmpGfx, CmpMatrix>()){
    updateGfx(comp.get<CmpGfx&>(), comp.get<CmpMatrix&>());
}
```